# aspectjweaver.jar conflicts with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, automated-tests, aspectj, allure

I have a spring-boot application for which i want to add the allure framework for order generation.

so we have an working spring boot app and i start to configure the pom.xml for the work with allure, namely, i add this in my pom:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.10.0</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Its already correct worked in app without spring.
But now after adding the configuration my spring-boot application starter crushed with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository$AjcClosure75
```

This rar include the full report which Aspectjweaver autogenered: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1soZMcNkDHvsFDkdPZoGLLgfrScoSZ_-O/view?usp=sharing

I localized the problem, it is in this lines:

```xml
<argLine>
    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
</argLine>
```

If remove it app starts without any errors but allure ignored @Step annotations.
How i can used spring-boot and allure anotations in one app?

Comment: I do not know Allure, but maybe you are somehow using regular Spring AOP proxies in your Spring Boot application, and when adding native AspectJ weaving to the mix you get conflicts between the two AOP frameworks. Maybe you need to use Allure with compile-time weaving so as not to interfere with Spring AOP, or maybe there is a special Allure config option for Spring. If you can provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, I can take a look. But just a POM snippet and the first line of a stack trace are really not enough for me to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I received error because i had spriring-boot-starter in parent:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

i understand it when reeding this: [AspectJ in Spring: CTW vs LTW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192521/aspectj-in-spring-ctw-vs-ltw)

now my pom like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.1.0</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
    <allure.version>2.18.1</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.9.1</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-selenide -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and i dont receive any error

Comment: this did not resolve the issue. how do you have a working pom without a mandatory section defined?